# Sencha touch charts 2: Dynamically create chart and load series from the store?

Tags: charts, touch, extjs

I want to create a scatter chart dynamically and load the series by fetching the data from the store. Is there any method to do that? I did the following:

```
var myChart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',{
  id:'myChart',
  renderTo:'myPanel',
  axes:[],  // blank because i need to add axes from store
  series:[] // blank because i need to add series from store
  :
  :
});

for(conditions){
  myChart.config.axes[0].fields.push(record[cnt].data.fieldName);
  var series = {
    type:'scatter',
    axis:['right', 'bottom'],
    xField:'myXfield',
    yField:record[cnt].data.yfieldVal
  }
  myChart.config.series.push(series);
}//for loop ends

myChart.redraw();
```

Iam not able to see the chart with the plots that are dynamically added.

Any help will be appriciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized how to address the issue. I declared Global variables for the store name and other related fields. I created the get and set methods. These are defined in app.js file. I was able to set the values dynamically to these global variables using set methods and use the assigned values using the get methods. I hope someone will be able to use this technique if required.